# Will installing multiple versions of Rails overwrite previous installations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

**What would happen if I keep typing in** `gem install rails` **using different versions of Rails?**

For instance, I can type in:

```
gem install rails --verson 3.2.10
```

or

```
gem install rails
```

which gives me version 3.2.12.

### Questions

1. **Will each installation overwrite the previous one?**
2. Will it remove all the old files and add the new version that I'm installing?
3. Or if I run it twice, it will keep some files?

I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will install two separate gems. The actual executable `rails` will invoke the newest version.

You can override that with

```
<gem_command> _<version>_
```

For example,

```
rails _3.2.10_
```

will execute Rails 3.2.10.

### Bundler

By the way, if we are talking about Ruby on Rails specifically, gems that are used in your app are controlled by [Bundler](http://bundler.io/). **Bundler looks at the Gemfile in the root of your app, and then figures out which versions to download, install and use all on its own.**

If you're a beginner, you don't have to worry about all that stuff at this point. `gem install rails`, and `rails new app` is all you need.

Comment: is it bad practice to have them both?

Comment: Absolutely not. By the way, if we are talking about Rails specifically, gems that are used in your app are controlled by bundler. Bundler looks at `Gemfile` in the root of your app and then figures out which versions to download, install and use all on its own. If you're a beginner, you don't have to worry about all that stuff at this point. `gem install rails`, `rails new app` is all you need

Comment: awesome pawsome! thanks! Yeah I'm a beginner, but I need to catch up with things asap! I understand `rails new app` but just trying to advance myself

Comment: You're welcome. If you're looking for resources, [this books](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) is free, up to date, and very practical covering pretty much all you need when getting started

Answer (score 1):

According to [enthrops's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15184043/456814), `gem` will install each version of Rails separately, so that they won't overwrite each other:

> It will install two separate gems. The actual executable `rails` will invoke the newest version.

If you're using [`rbenv`](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) to manage your Ruby installations, then you can find the directory for each Rails installation in paths of the form

```
~/.rbenv/versions/<rubyVersion>/lib/ruby/gems/<rubyVersion>/gems/rails-<version>
```

For example, on my machine, I have the following versions of Rails installed:

```
$ ls -l ~/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/ | \
$ grep --extended-regexp "(\s)rails-"
drwxr-xr-x  4 foobar staff  136 May 13 19:07 rails-4.0.0
drwxr-xr-x  4 foobar staff  136 May 13 18:41 rails-4.0.5
drwxr-xr-x  4 foobar staff  136 Apr 19 21:27 rails-4.1.0
```